# Visual Studio C++ is there a faster way to set breakpoint values?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Every time a breakpoint is hit I need to input a specific variable value, but inputting them manually is very time consuming, is there a faster way? The code cannot be modified. Ideally it would be nice to have another Visual Studio app that could feed values to the other Visual Studio C++ Locals window. What is the easiest way to solve this?

Comment: This sounds to me like your code lacks unit tests. A unit test should be able to feed values into a bit of code, and then you could debug that test. So make sure you can compile the code you want to test to a (static) lib and start writing unit tests

Comment: I never said it was my code, its code I'm supposed to test

Comment: I never said it was your code but that doesn't mean it can still be lacking unit tests ;)
And making (parts of) existing code unit testable can be worth it. (I will even say, it will be worth it)

Comment: Ideally yes, but it's not allowed to be modified otherwise it would have been easy to test.

Comment: Classical chicken and egg problem. You're not allowed to change code because someone is afraid the code will break because there are no unit tests. You can still copy parts of the code to a new library and test that.  My advice give feedback to your organization that they are at risk. For now the only thing you can do is just take your time debugging, there is no faster way and that (oversimplified) is not your problem (but your organizations problem, their lack of quality is now costing you extra time)

Comment: makes sense thanks

Comment: Ignore all those commenting on your test method.  Regardless of what you should or should not do for test (even if you had the authority to dictate that in your team), it remains a legitimate debug technique for many purposes besides test, so a fair question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the debugger breakpoint actions feature.  The actions dialog suggests that it can only be used to print messages in the output window, but any expression between `{...}` is evaluated, so it can be used to coerce variables or call functions for example.

Example:

1. First create a breakpoint and right-click it and select "Actions...":[image]
2. Set the action as required: [image]`{i = i == 10 ? 99990 : i}` in this example.
3. Run

   [image]

Here when `i == 10` `i` is set to 99990 to skip forward in the loop in this case.

I tried using it in conjunction with the breakpoint condition, but could not get that to work in the way I would expect; YMMV.

You can do more complex actions by invoking a function in the action expression.  For example given a function:

```cpp
int test( int i )
{
    return i == 10 ? 99990 : i;
}
```

You can invoke it from the action expression thus: `{i=test(i)}`.  It does nothing more in this case than the previous example, but demonstrates that a function can be invokes.  The function can of course do much more.

If you want to inject a sequence of test values into a variable, you might have an action expression say: `{i = getTestData()}` where `getTestData()` is a function *you* write and link to the code under test.  It might for example read a sequence of values from a file.

Of course your test function will need to be in scope at the breakpoint site, and that would normally entail modifying the code to include a header, or prototype or the actual function.  That can be avoided by using a [*forced include*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fi-name-forced-include-file?view=msvc-170).
[image]

Then all your test stimulus files can be in separately linked modules and the code itself will not need modification for test.

Note that hitting a breakpoint evaluating the action expression and continuing, will significantly slow down the execution when invoked frequently.

Comment: @AmadeusBojiuc  You are welcome, but see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.  Specifically the last paragraph. No thanks required, up-votes or acceptance gratefully received ;-).

Comment: is it possible to have something like { i == Convert.Int32(File.ReadAllText(some path...))}?

Comment: @AmadeusBojiuc  I have no idea.  Is that a [.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-7.0) call?  Suggesting C++/CLI?  I have never used it.  But as I posted in the edit, you can invoke a simple function interface to perform more complex actions, and I would suggest doing that.  Far more maintainable than setting complex action expressions - and they can be checked-in to your version control system and more easily managed than a project XML file.

Comment: @AmadeusBojiuc ... not `==` though, that is a Boolean expression, not an assignment.